# Getting rooms that are free between two dates MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in MySQL. First is a Room.
and second is Reservation.
In Table reservation i have Room_Id and Reservation_DateFrom and Reservation_DateTo
How can i make a query that take two random dates for example (12-12-2012 and 21-12-2012) and see if the specific room is free all of the days from 12-12-2012 to 21-12-2012 if i have
DateFrom and DateTo for rooms in Reservation. I want to list all rooms that are available for rent on these days. For example if Room 1 has reservation from 15-12-2012 to 20-12-2012 
it will not return it because some days from 12-12-2012 to 21-12-2012 are already reserved.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you written any code? Reservations has been discussed **a lot** recently - have you looked around for solutions?

Comment: reservations for some people from the past? 2012? hehe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Ro.*
 FROM Room Ro 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Reservation Re 
                   WHERE Ro.Id = Re.Room_Id
                   AND ([yourStartDate] BETWEEN Re.Reservation_DateFrom AND Re.Reservation_DateTo
                        OR [yourEndDate] BETWEEN Re.Reservation_DateFrom AND Re.Reservation_DateTo)
                   )
```

it'll grab rooms that don't have any reservations that collide with your date range.